# How to take photo by monitor instead of viewfinder with my new Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, live-view

I am a starter with Digital SLRs and I just bought a Nikon D5100.

One thing I can not figure out is how to take photos from the monitor, not
from viewfinder. What I can see is the photo information on the screen but
not the scene. I think it is a dumb question but I just don't know how to 
work it out.

Comment: Just a note - it's much easier to hold the camera stable if you use the viewfinder and not the monitor.  Use the monitor to actually take photos only when using the viewfinder is inconvenient, or when the camera is mounted on a sturdy tripod.

Answer (score 16):

Page 44 in [your manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf)!

The part you're probably looking for is (quoted from the manual):

> Rotate the live view switch. The mirror will be raised and the view
>   through the lens
>       will be displayed in the camera monitor. The subject will no longer be visible in the
>       viewfinder.

The live view switch is located next to your mode dial and is indicated wit `Lv`

[image: live mode]

Comment: Dear friend,thank you so much helping me to solve this puzzle. I can be very happy to plan with it now.